# Error when changing axis format with scale_x_date

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

Dear fellow homo sapiens,

I've created [this](http://tinypic.com/r/axcg1h/6) graph using the code below (except without `+ scale_x_date`).

The data-set that I've used to do this is found [HERE](http://www.sendspace.com/file/m2qzko). It looks like this:

```
GFC1CARi<-read.csv("demo.csv")
head(GFC1CARi)
  X         XX   variable       value    Var
1 1 2008-07-17 Financials 0.001772705 Financ
2 2 2008-07-18 Financials 0.017306086 Financ
3 3 2008-07-21 Financials 0.010745136 Financ
4 4 2008-07-22 Financials 0.021152194 Financ
5 5 2008-07-23 Financials 0.031195805 Financ
6 6 2008-07-24 Financials 0.026534444 Financ
```

As you'll see the in picture, the x-axis displays dates such as "Aug", "Sep" .... . However, I want it to be something similar to "08/2007", "09/2007" ... . So, my attempt at doing this is displayed below, but it doesn't work.

```
p <- ggplot(data=GFC1CARi,aes(x=XX, y=value, colour=Var)) +
        geom_line() + 
        opts(legend.position = "none") + 
        xlab(" ") + 
        ylab("Cumulative abnormal return") + 
        scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%m/%Y"),breaks = "1 month")

p <- direct.label(p+xlim(min(GFC1CARi$XX), max(GFC1CARi$XX)+20))
```

I've tried many other variation of `breaks = ??` and `date_format` and I can't get the %m/%Y to show, it'll always be "Aug" .. "Sep" .. "Oct". As requested by Joran:

```
> str(GFC1CARi)
'data.frame':   1730 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ X       : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ XX      : POSIXct, format: "2008-07-17" "2008-07-18" "2008-07-21" "2008-07-22" ...
 $ variable: Factor w/ 10 levels "Financials","Industrials",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ value   : num  0.00177 0.01731 0.01075 0.02115 0.0312 ...
 $ Var     : chr  "Financ" "Financ" "Financ" "Financ" ...
```

I've even tried to change the date formate from  `POSIXct`  to `as.Date` as follows:

```
GFC1CARi[,2]<-as.Date(GFC1CARi[,2])
str(GFC1CARi)
'data.frame':   1730 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ X       : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ XX      : Date, format: "2008-07-16" "2008-07-17" ...
 $ variable: Factor w/ 10 levels "Financials","Industrials",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ value   : num  0.000983 0.015822 0.008339 0.017987 0.027186 ...
 $ Var     : chr  "Financ" "Financ" "Financ" "Financ" ...
```

This doesn't fix the situation. Instead the X-axis is now { "Oct", "Jan", "Apr" }, and that's it.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Works fine for me. Can you verify that you actually have dates stored in `XX` by showing us the output from `str(GFC1CARi)`?

Comment: Also, the system was trying to prompt you to write a _more_ informative title by complaining about the word "problem", not a _less_ informative title by inserting a random letter to get around it.

Comment: @joran - I don't have any probdlems with their original title.

Comment: I no longer get that error message, but I still can't get the correct x-axis labels, as described in my O.P.. @joran That was a genuine typo.

Comment: @Dason I suppose I should clarify that that "feature" is also one of the most hated by many on meta, particularly when someone wants to ask a legit question about "the halting problam".

Comment: I do get the correct labels (and apologies about assuming about the title!). Just a thought, try switch from POSIX to Date using `as.Date`.

Comment: @joran Thanks for guidance; I tried this and it didn't work (see my edited OP for details) :)

Comment: I'm running out of stuff to suggest, since I'm still getting exactly the graph that you say you want. Make sure you're versions of ggplot and R are up to date, perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My apologies, I was being very dense. I thought the error you were getting was happening *before* the attempt to use `directlabels`, not *after*.

The call to `xlim` is simply stomping on the x axis formatting. Just put the `scale_x_date` call inside the `direct.labels` command works for me:

```
p <- direct.label(p + 
                  xlim(min(dat$XX), max(dat$XX)+20) + 
                  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%m/%Y"),breaks = "1 month"))
```

[image]